# Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$term_id

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am facing this problem .

> Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$term_id search.php on line 53

And here is my code.

```
if($category_name != "All") {
        $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
            if(isset($thisCat)){
                $catSearchID = $thisCat->term_id;
            }

    } else {
        $catSearchID = '-1';
    }
```

Any body help please? 
Thanks

Comment: The error is pretty clear, the `term_id` property of `$thisCat` object isn't defined. Instead of `$catSearchID = $thisCat->term_id;`, do a `print_r($thisCat);` To see what properties the object contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. 
I was using custom search form , but when i try to search from WordPress Default search widget that this problem was shown. I just place this code.

```
if(isset($_GET['category_name'])){
        if($category_name != "All") {           
            $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
                if(isset($thisCat)){
                    $catSearchID = $thisCat->term_id;
                }

        } else {
            $catSearchID = '-1';
        }
    }
```

And Now My Problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$term_id search.php on line 53

This error is very clear, term_id property is not the part of $thisCat.

**For solution**,

Do not pass the second parameter in `get_query_var()` function. its an optional parameter default empty.

Comment: Already try that , But not solved. $thisCat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));